# How to send one report to different clients using ssrs subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that need to be sent to different clients, I have a parameter accepting the company name, so I want to loop through my parameter and sent the report to a list of those companies and need to filter the report by company name, the user only need to see the data for his company.

Hope my question is clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a Data Driven Subscription. First create a stored procedure that can be used to return EmailAddresses, CC_EmailAddresses, and BCC_EmailAddresses. Since your distribution will go to many customers and you may not want each customer to see the other customer's email address, as a good practice return the customer email addresses in the BCC_EmailAddresses, you will still however be required to have the EmailAddresses return at least one email address. Next follow the prompts to create a Data Driven Subscription. See screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A data-driven subscription will do what you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx